# Instantiate from two values, each in separate array

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem with Instantiating `GameObject`s from `float`s in arrays, which I have to merge into one `Vector2` (or `Vector3`). I have only two values in arrays:

```
GameObject = somePrefab
float[] = value1
float[] = value2
```

First I have to combine them into a vector, then Instantiate as many prefabs as the combined vector number is...

Can anybody help me with how to merge these `float`s into a vector and instantiate?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Is "the combined vector number" the vector's length/magnitude, or something else? Try telling us about how this is being used in your game. Understanding the gameplay application can help us put this in context.

Comment: Is it save to assume that both float vectors are the same size?

Comment: These are coordinates from "Input.location.lastData.latitiude & Input.location.lastData.longitude".

I have two values and I have to pass it to Vector2d (MapboxSDK for Unity)
Then I need to Instantiate Pin on map based on Vector2d, the point is I can pass only one value LatLong, merged together.

What I tried is:

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                _locations[i] = new Vector2d(pointsLat[i], pointsLong[i]);
            }

It`s merging them but I have :Out if range exception" and it`s not auto filling _locations[i] , I need to type myself size of array.